# sched_yield slow down other threads

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

We have code that makes use of `sched_yield` inside a loop. When we do this we seem to get a slower performance of other threads, in particular those involving kernel calls (like IO and mutex/event handling).  I'm trying to determine the exact cause of this behaviour.

Can excessive calls to `sched_yield` lead to a bottleneck in the kernel?

My suspicion is if we keep asking the kernel to check its process list then other threads will suffer as key data structures may be continually locked -- whereas if we didn't call `sched_yield` those kernel locks would tend to be uncontested. Does this make sense, or should it be totally okay to repeatedly call `sched_yield`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [`sched_yield`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_yield.2.html) man page for Linux:

> Avoid calling sched_yield()
>          unnecessarily or inappropriately (e.g., when resources needed by other
>          schedulable threads are still held by the caller), since doing so will result
>          in **unnecessary context switches, which will degrade system performance**.

Calling it in a tight loop will cause problems. Reduce the rate at which you're calling it.

(And check that you need to call it in the first place. The scheduler often does the Right Thing all by itself.)

Other options you could find interesting to investigate if you have a low priority thread:

- [`sched_setscheduler`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html) - with `SCHED_IDLE` or `SCHED_BATCH` maybe (affects the whole process)
- [`thread_setschedparam`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html) - per thread, but might have restrictions on what policies you can use (can't find it right now).

Or the good old [`nice`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/nice.2.html) command of course.

Comment: The thread calling `sched_yield` in our system won't be blocking other threads in any way. The idea is that some other thread may have released a resource which now unblocks yet another thread. So I don't care about loss of performance in the thread calling `sched_yield`, but only in those other threads.

Comment: Read the bold part: it degrades **system** performance, not only the calling thread. Context switching is relatively light in Linux, but not free. Too much of it will slow the whole system down.

Comment: I guess I'll have to look at other options then. Perhaps I'll ask another question.

Comment: Do you need another option? Can't you just reduce the rate at which you're issuing that system call?

Comment: Well, that'll be the first option.  Ultimately I just want a thread that *should* be preempted at any given moment by any other thread that can now process (and not have to wait for the full timeslice to end).

Comment: Updated my answer with other things you might want to investigate.