# Openmp thread sleep

Tags: c++, openmp

I am currently working on a project to design Airport with OOP. I am using c++. I have a main Airport object in my program which has RequestLanding() function which assigns the runway number on which plane can land. This function returns one of the two enums- Hold or Proceed to indicate whether plane should land or not.

From the outside there are many airplane objects which makes the landing request. I am using for loop for the total number of airplane objects. I am using OpenMp for parallel loop. I wanted to make a thread of openmp sleep for 3 seconds when the  RequestLanding() function returns the state Hold and then try again.

Is there a way to do this ? Can someone provide a simple example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not using `yield` rahter than sleeping?

Comment: @user0042 Assuming you mean `std::this_thread::yield` - I highly recommend against that. On Linux it maps to `sched_yield`, and `sched_yield` is implemented in a way that is absolutely not suitable to be called in a tight loop. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/6807929/620382

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do something that will be very bad.

You should not manually poll (repeatedly check for a condition) in a thread - with or without sleeping - unless you really know what you are doing. Instead use a proper construct like a condition variable to signal readiness. The specific right way to do it depends on the specific use case.

In OpenMP, a thread is a worker that handles multiple things, such as a loop iteration. You must not unnecessary delay it as you will delay the other things (loop iterations, airplanes) that it is supposed to handle.

In OpenMP, tasks would be slightly more suitable to handle airplane object. However, while tasks can have dependencies, they are only between sibling tasks or loop iterations, so that doesn't help you. You can also `taskyield` in OpenMP tasks, but I would be very careful in making any assumptions.

As an example how things can and will go horribly wrong: Let's say you have a thread for each airplane and call `std::this_thread::yield` hence `sched_yield` in a tight loop checking the condition. You might think the airplanes that are blocked will let the other airplanes use the CPU. You would be wrong. The current Linux scheduler will still give the blocked airplanes the same amount of CPU time than the ones who want to do actual work. I would hope that `omp taskyield` is implemented in a better way, but I would not count on it.

At the same time, calling `sleep` in any form will introduce an artificial delay.